# Is it discouraged to call a Windows command line from a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

What are the cons of calling a windows cmd from a Python script, compared to running Python code with equivalent functionality?

My code is as follows :

```
import subprocess
def runWinCmd(cmd):
    result = []
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in process.stdout:
        result.append(line)

    errcode = process.returncode

    return errcode
```

Comment: What is your question? cons about what? what to you compare it to?

Comment: Where will you be deploying your code?

Comment: I would say that it is purely opinion based.

Comment: I guess this comes dows to the advantages and disadvantages of Windows and it is highly opinion based.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I don't see why it is opinion based.. it is experience-based. If any issues encountered when calling windows command line from Python. For example more care must be done when calling from a Java code as it relies on JVM, and so Garbage Collector.

Comment: "What are the cons of calling a windows cmd from a Python script?" Compared against what exactly? Compared against running PowerShell commands? Or compared against running unix terminal commands? Or compared against running python code with equivalent functionality? Or something something else?

Comment: Thank you Xukrao for the question. Compared to running Python code with equivalent functionality. I'm going to do an edit to add this detail

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `cmd` in this context. There are many command-line programs that have nothing to do with the "CMD" shell, and they can be quite useful in a pinch, especially the ones that use the native Unicode command-line and can be configured to write Unicode (UTF-16 or UTF-8) to a pipe. Some will even output XML or CSV, which is easy to parse reliably in Python compared to parsing tabular or free-form output. These programs should be executed with the default `shell=False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
```

The argument `shell=True` cann be a security hazard.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

> Warning: Using shell=True can be a security hazard. See the warning under Frequently Used Arguments for details.

[More](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> Warning: Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

An example:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> filename = input("What file would you like to display?\n")
What file would you like to display?
non_existent; rm -r dir1 / #  {delete something -- like a directory} 
>>> call("cat " + filename, shell=True) # Uh-oh. This will end badly...
```

Comment: I was wondering if it was a good idea to put this rm rf as an example? Because this would indeed end badly if a real beginner wanted to try this.

Comment: Thank you to have brought my attention on security issues, as I was only wondering if there would be any memory issues (beginner in Python).

Comment: @vgalin. Edited.

Comment: @Farah. That will certainly depend on the application.

Comment: BTW, there's no `rm` Windows shell command.

Comment: @martineau  Yeah you are right.

Comment: Use Python's `shutil.rmtree()` to avoid having to create a new heavyweight cmd.exe process.

Comment: @lit: I think you're missed the main point of this answer, which isn't really about _how_ to delete directories.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use the build in lib. See `os.system()`.

Comment: But that was not what the question was about